# Get startdate and enddate of a every week within the specified date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get startdate and enddate of a every week within the specified date range for eg:  I want start_date of week and end_date of week within 2021-01-01 and 2022-12-31

But want week_start_date as 2021-01-01 for the first week and 2021-12-31 as end date of the 52nd week at the end of the year .

Table should fill like this if start_date is: 2021-01-01 and 2022-12-31

```
week_start date             week_end_date
2021-01-01                   2021-01-02
2021-01-03                   2021-01-09
2021-01-10                   2021-01-16
.
.
.
.
.
.
2021-12-26                  2021-12-31
2022-01-01                  2022-01-01
2022-01-02                  2022-01-08
.
.
```

How to give first_week_date (year no matter what)-01-01 and end_week_date( year no matter what)-12-31  and in between the logic should be able to calculate week_start_date and week_end_date without problem.

I am using SQL Server for this implementation

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: ok will do like this next time

Comment: SQL standard defines to date functions, so your question is unanswerable without specifying what implementation you're using.

Comment: You call `2021-12-21 -> 2021-12-31` a week? That's closer to two weeks. ANd the first week in 2022 is a single day. I sort of understand what you're looking for here but I really don't know the practical purpose of a week being defined as anything between 1 and 11 days. Anyway a calendar table where you define the week boundaries one time is going to be your answer; anything else will have to account for DATEFIRST or LANGUAGE settings, or use cryptic date math to avoid that dependency.

Comment: Hi @mamta If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
DECLARE @fromDate DATE = '2021-01-01';
DECLARE @toDate DATE = '2021-12-31';

SELECT CASE WHEN WeekStart<@fromDate THEN @fromDate ELSE WeekStart END AS week_start_date,
CASE WHEN WeekEnd>@toDate THEN @toDate ELSE WeekEnd END AS week_end_date
FROM
(
   SELECT DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, date_column)-1), date_column) AS 'WeekStart',
     DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, date_column)), date_column) AS 'WeekEnd'
   FROM table_name
   WHERE date_column BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
) a;
```

Where,

`table_name` is the name of your table.

`date_column` is the name of the column containing the date.

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the table requested:

```
DECLARE @minDate DateTime = '20210101'
DECLARE @maxDate DateTime = '20221231';

WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
    ,lv4 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b) -- 65,536
    ,lv5 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv4 a CROSS JOIN lv4 b) -- 4,294,967,296
    ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv5)
    ,DateList AS (
       SELECT TOP (dateDiff(day,@minDate,@maxDate)+1) 
         @minDate+n-1 AS DateValue 
       FROM Tally) 

SELECT 
  datepart(year,DateValue) AS [Year],
  datepart(week,DateValue) AS [Week],
  min(dateValue) AS StartDate,
  max(dateValue) AS EndDate
FROM DateList
GROUP BY
  datepart(year,DateValue),
  datepart(week,DateValue)
ORDER BY 3
```